# How to auto-scale google dataflow (streaming) pipeline?

Tags: publish-subscribe, dataflow, google-dataflow

We have streaming pipeline running in Google Dataflow. It pulls Pub/Sub message and saves into BigQuery. For some reason, in last few day we have backlog. System lag shows 9-15 hours. I follow [document here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-autoscaling), and added following params:

```
--autoscaling_algorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED
--max_num_workers=5
```

However, it does not seems spawning new pipeline. We have pull Pub/Sub.

Comment: Have you hit the `max_num_workers` already?

Comment: Yes, but no effect